# Moving directory from remote host to local

Tags: bash

I need to copy a directory from a remote host to my local laptop. I have seen from previous posts that in order to do that I type,

```
scp -r user@remotehost.ac.uk:/path/to/dirtory/ /home/user/Desktop
```

But I get,

```
/home/user/Desktop: No such file or directory
```

why is that happening?

Comment: Check if `/home/user/Desktop` does exist on your laptop. Here `user` is the username, Sketos, for example.

Comment: well, does the directory exists at all ?

Comment: Check if directory `/home/user/Desktop` exists? if exists then do you have write permission?

Comment: it exists ( this is the standard path for your desktop in linux after all ) and actually sketos is the user name.

Comment: Problem solved! i was logged to the remote host when i was trying to do this

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
scp -r user@remotehost.ac.uk:/path/to/dirtory/ /home/user/Desktop
```

The following will happen:

- the command will connect to user@remotehost.ac.uk
- it will try to copy this folder "/path/to/dirtory/" to the specified location "/home/user/Desktop"

The thing is that folder "/home/user/Desktop" must exist on your computer. You should check that the "/user/" actually exists, maybe you mistyped.